# Merging two arrays together doesn't do anything

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
int[] mergeArrays(int[] a, int[] b){

    int[] c = new int [a.length+b.length];

    for(int i=0; i > c.length; i++){
        if(a[i] >= b[i]){
            c[i] = a[i];
        }
        else
            c[i] = b[i];
        }
    }

    return c;

}
```

This is my method for merging two arrays with different values and combining same values. The output is supposed to be a new array containing all the values from both arrays and combining the same values of said arrays.

When I pass two arrays in this method and print out the returning array, it seems as though the for loop doesn't do anything, as the values stay zeroes. What's the reason that new values aren't assigned to the c[] array going through the for loop?

Comment: After fixing the condition of your for loop, are you sure indexing all three arrays by the same index `i` is what is needed here?

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Evidently not. What would be a proper way to index these two arrays so they don't go out of exception while going through the loop?

Comment: "it's easier asking here" That doesn't matter. You have a new question, so create a new post.

Comment: You need one counter for each array, for a total of three counters. This has the smell of a school assignment. If I were doing this in real life,  I'd load them all into an array and then use sort ().

Comment: Youre right, so using prebuilt methods like sort() isn't the point. I guess I need counters, but I'm not sure how I would implement that in this logic.

Comment: Just an observation, why is the length of c the combined length of a and b? Based on your code it seems like a and b are of equal length, and it seems like this code would be guaranteed to give you an out of bounds exception. Shouldn't the length be the same as that of b or a so that there isnt an out of bounds exception?

Comment: No, two arrays aren't necessarily the same length, that's why I combined those lengths to make sure, but evidently, that's not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are unioning two sorted arrays and want the result to also be sorted. To do this you'll need two counters (one per input array).

```
int ait = 0;
int bit = 0;
while(true) {
    if(ait < a.length && bit < b.length) {
        if(a[ait] <= b[bit])
            c[ait+bit] = a[ait++];
        else
            c[ait+bit] = b[bit++];
    } else if(ait < a.length) {
        c[ait+bit] = a[ait++];
    } else if(bit < b.length) {
        c[ait+bit] = b[bit++];
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is (almost) exactly what I need. I just have to add the condition to remove double values.

Comment: Skipping duplicates is going to result in 0-valued indexes in `c`. Since you want sorting and uniqueness, you might consider `Set<Integer>` and then exporting back to `int[]` once you've gone through.
It'll be a lot more expressive of your intent.

Answer (score 2):

You have written i > c.length in the for loop, it must be i < c.length

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Thanks.

Comment: While I understand you wish to be helpful, questions which are simply typos are off-topic on this site, because they are unlikely to be helpful to future readers.  You should be flagging these questions, and once you have enough reputation, make a comment to that effect.

Comment: Should I delete my question for this reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
  List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    temp.add(a[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (!temp.contains(b[i])) {
      temp.add(b[i]);
    }
  }
  Collections.sort(temp);
  int[] result = temp.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
  return result;
}
```

This code will server your purpose. We cannot construct the final array with size by adding the 2 arrays. Because your concern is to eliminate duplicate values. So construct a List with the values and then convert it to int[].

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this method is that the way it combines arrays is it puts in the values of one array then the values of another. What I need to do is return an array with values already sorted in an ascending order.

Comment: Your final array is to be sorted in ascending order. Is that correct?

Comment: Two arrays are supposed to be already sorted in the ascending order, so the newly returned array should be as well.

Comment: Sorting the output is not a big deal. 

I will update the code.